# MongoDB's GridFS, Rails 3, X-Sendfile, and ACL's, HOW-TO?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, acl, x-sendfile, gridfs

I have a Rails 3 project that does file upload/download, with access rights (User has many Files, and can only read/write his own files).

If I store my files on classic filesystem, I can check the access to the file in my rails app and then use X-Sendfile header to redirect to the file, if user has access. In this way, a user can never access a file without permission, and the download is fast.

1. Can I make file download from GridFS as fast as X-Sendfile, and skip the hassle of piping them trough rails/rack ?
2. Piping them trough rails/rack would be horribly slow ?
3. Can I make file download from GridFS as fast as X-Sendfile, and skip the hassle of piping them trough rails/rack, **AND ALSO** have the ability to enforce access rights ?

Comment: guess I'll just use something like [rack-gridfs](http://github.com/skinandbones/rack-gridfs) and prey it's fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until now I've found and thought of to possible solutions:

1. Use something like [gridfs-fuse](http://github.com/mikejs/gridfs-fuse/) to mount the GFS to local FS and use X-Sendfile just as allways.
2. Use something like [nginx-gridfs](http://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs/) which is c-fast and out-of-rails (does not block my app's req-resp cycle while downloading). The downside is that it's server specific

Comment: nginx-gridfs looks like a nice solution, however the current version fails to compile and due to many issues it might suffer from memory leaks. I would be very careful with using it in production